# Circuit/Capacitance Question

Tags: electric-circuits, potential, capacitance, voltage, conventions

How do you know which is the "top plate" in circuit diagrams? I am having trouble determining whether circuits are in series or parallel and I watched a video which determined to look at electric flow from the top plate. Here is an example of the kind of images I am looking at.  [image]

Comment: Couldn't understand the "top plates". You mean to say the positive terminal?

Answer (score 2):

Assume a DC voltage source, and please excuse the "low level" recommendation, but it should illustrate what you are dealing with.  Take a red crayon, start on the top wire, and color every wire that is connected to the top wire red.  One side of C1 and C2 will be connected to the red wire, so they will see the same voltage.  On the other side of C1 and C2, take a blue crayon, and color every wire that is connected to this side of the capacitors.  Every blue wire is at the same voltage.  This means that C1 and C2 are connected in parallel.  Now, take a green crayon, and color the wire on the left side of C3.

Assuming voltage "V" at the top terminal, and voltage "0" on the bottom terminal, all of the red wires are at voltage "V", all of the blue wires are at a voltage less than "V" but greater than 0, and the green wire is at 0 volts.

Since there are capacitors in series in this circuit, I will leave it up to the OP to designate "top plate/bottom plate" for each capacitor.